# Plot a special integral function

Tags: sympy

I am a newbye on Sympy.
I try to plot the function:

```
plot(Integral((t*ln(abs(2+t)))/((1+t**2)),(t,0,x)))
```

The important check to exercise is to look around the"singular" point of the integrating function.
I have a strange behaviour of tool on -2 bound.
Does it exist (into Sympy) a different plotting methods to obtain the global function behaviour without split the integral on 2 pieces ?
What does it happen on -2 bound that collapse the Sympy algorithm?
Integration on over (t,-3,-1) works.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is a case where the plotting module in unable to evaluate the expression. We can workaround it: we use sympy's `lambdify` to convert the symbolic expression to a numerical function. Then we use numpy and matplotlib to create a plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

expr = Integral((t*ln(abs(2+t)))/((1+t**2)),(t,0,x))
f1 = lambdify([x], expr)
# since the expression contains an integral, we need to vectorize
# the numerical function so that it will automatically evaluate
# a numpy array
f1 = np.vectorize(f1)
f2 = lambdify([x], expr.diff(x))
f2 = np.vectorize(f2)

xx = np.linspace(-4, 0, 1000)
yy1 = f1(xx)
yy2 = f2(xx)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
def grid_labels(ax, ylabel):
    ax.grid(which='major', axis='both', linewidth=0.75,
        linestyle='-', color='0.85')
    ax.grid(which='minor', axis='both', linewidth=0.25,
        linestyle='--', color='0.80')
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    
axs[0].plot(xx, yy1)
grid_labels(axs[0], "f(x)")
axs[1].plot(xx, yy2)
grid_labels(axs[1], "df/dx")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @David_sd Thank you very very much for your help and pills.So we can assume (as general rule) that  when we treat with "singolarity" functions-point , the plotting way (on Sympy environment) is working with numerical method. Is it correct?

Comment: The plotting module automatically does what I've done in the answer: it converts the symbolic expression to a numerical function, it evaluates it, and finally plots the results. Sadly, the current plotting module uses "a much older version" of `lambdify`, which is clearly incapable of plotting this particular expression. Either way, the current plotting module doesn't do any "singularity" detection. In this example, we can visually spot the singularity after plotting the derivative.